# How to disable firebase phone number authentication reCapcha in react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How to disable google firebase authentication ReCaptcha in the react native? I referred to so many resources I haven't found any solution.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";
import firebase from "../Firebase/Firebase";

export default Phone = () => {
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = React.useState();
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = React.useState();
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const firebaseConfig = firebase.apps.length
    ? firebase.app().options
    : undefined;
  const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  const sendVerification = () => {
  const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
  phoneProvider
    .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)
    .then(setVerificationId)
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
      return;
    });
  console.log(setVerificationId);
  };
  const confirmCode = () => {
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId,
      code
    );
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.user);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Phone Number"
          onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
          keyboardType="phone-pad"
          autoCompleteType="tel"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={sendVerification}>
          <Text>Send Verification</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Confirmation Code"
          onChangeText={setCode}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={confirmCode}>
          <Text>Send Verification</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
          ref={recaptchaVerifier}
          firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Recapcha is optional you are able to use phone auth without it.

```
const confirmResult = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+' + phone);
setState(confirmResult);
```

to confirm code manually

```
if (confirmResult && receivedcode) {
  const user = await confirmResult.confirm(receivedcode);
  if (user) { //do some staff like login }
}
```

to auto confirm just put the following code inside `useEffect` function.

```
unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
   if (user) { //do some staff like login }
});
```

If you dont know where `auth` comes from:

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
```

Comment: I am using expo , react-native-firebase/auth library will support for expo ??

Comment: It seems to support it: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/#user-authentication

Answer (score 0):

if you're using expo then you can just put this prop in FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal like this it will manage rest

```
<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
{...}
attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
/>
```